# How to use specs2 to test spray-swagger REST API endpoints?

Tags: swagger, spray, specs2

[spray-swagger](https://github.com/gettyimages/spray-swagger) appears to be a good way to auto-generate documentation as well as client stubs for a REST API. Is there a way to automatically test these APIs using [specs2](http://specs2.org)?